# Unanswered question sort order

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting

I decided to spend a few minutes during my lunch break looking at questions with no answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

I'm not a particularly brilliant person; most questions on Stack Overflow are out of my league. Questions with zero answers tend to be WAY out of my league, otherwise somebody else would have answered them.

A small part of me has a small shred of hope that perhaps there are some niche questions out there that I might have an answer to, because I do deal with some unique challenges every now and then. It would be tremendously helpful if I could sort the questions with no answers to show questions that have tags I'm interested in at the beginning and questions with tags I'm not interested in at the end.

Comment: If you add favorite and ignored tags, questions with those tags will be appropriately highlighted or dimmed in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you *want* is the [my tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) section, which lists unanswered questions in the tags you spend a lot of time in (or alternately, have explicitly set as your "favorites" if you have some of those).

Note that this also includes questions that *do have* answers, but only when none of the answers scores above 0... Meaning they either still need an answer that *works*, or one of the existing answers needs an up-vote. In general, this is more useful than simply listing questions with *zero* answers, as it avoids the problem of interesting niche questions being hidden when someone without any real knowledge of that particular niche has tried to answer (and then failed).

Though [as Grace Notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/unanswered-question-sort-order/109296#109296), you can always craft a custom search that'll list questions meeting whatever criteria you chose to follow. If you click on the aforementioned "my tags" tab and then look in the search box at top-right, a search including your tags is already there, waiting for you to refine it...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use that utility, why not narrow the scope down to exclude the questions with tags you aren't interested in? The search term `answers:0` will narrow down results to explicitly those with 0 answers, which is basically all that tab does.

Combine that with a search for your interesting tags (easiest if you have few, naturally), and you'll end up with all of the currently non-answered questions in those tags. And then you can further sort the results using whatever active/newest/vote sort you want to use.